Image in README via cdn url does not show on NPM page
I have a publicly visible image. Url to the image is this:
https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uni-module-common/img/action1.png?raw=true
When I use this url in a README file in my NPM repository, the image is not shown on the NPM page.
This is how I define the image:
## Action
**Description**: Action icon with a hover effect based on application theme. Can be used either by itself or as a child of an action menu (three dots menu).

![][https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uni-module-common/img/action1.png?raw=true]

And this is how it is being displayed by NPM:

I searched a lot of articles and everywhere they say that this should work, but it simply doesn't.
Does anyone have any advice?
Thanks, Vojtech

I figured it out in the end.
Instead of this:
![][https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uni-module-common/img/action1.png?raw=true]

I must type this:
![](https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/uni-module-common/img/action1.png?raw=true)

(Wrong bracket type)
